# Using a cute object into another object without make it GLOBAL?

Tags: php, class, object, global-variables

My friend adviced me: `Jesus, man! Don't use GLOBALs. It makes your software slow.`

**This is my way:**

```
// Database class
class DB extends mysqli { ... }

// create Database object
$db = new DB(...)

// My class
class A {
  function foo(){
    global $db; ## PROBLEM IS HERE

    $db->get_all(...);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to use `$db` object **without make it GLOBAL**? or should I stop to listen to my friend?

Comment: Passing `$db` into your class on construction as @Darragh says is probably the best and easiest way, but I can't see how using `global` could have any noticable effect on performance (unless you were throwing hundreds of globals around, maybe)

Comment: @Ben: Now, with your help, I don't use GLOBALS anymore -and I don't know, maybe my friend would be a little bit obsessed about GLOBALS. Thanks for answer Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just create a property for your `$db` object and pass it into object `A`, via the constructor (or create a setter method):

```
class A
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function foo()
    {
        $this->db->get_all(...);
    }
}

// create your objects. inject the DB object into object A
$db = new DB();
$a = new A($db);
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: If there is no better way, that's the answer. Simple and cute! Thanks thought ;)